# My Droid Packagemap has no visible packages (deleted them all) and when I try to add a new version of Xamarin it gives me an error

Tags: android, forms, xamarin

Been having alot of trouble with Android in xamarin and as my title says, i removed everything, xamarin.forms and all of its necessities (android.support) so the packagemap is completely empty. However when I try to readd a Xamarin.Forms package it gives me this error (as if it's still packages in there):

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.0.1.3)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.0.1.3)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (≥ 23.0.1.3)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.1.1.0)'.
Updating 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 23.0.1.3' to 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 23.1.1.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 'Xamarin.Forms' that is compatible with 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 23.1.1.0'.
```

Is there anyway I can delete the Packagemap and make a new one somehow? Something is clearly very wrong here because It looks like it is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try this:

  rebuild > refresh folder references > add packages >  Xamarin forms
  (2.1.0.6524) > rebuild  Xamarin.form package will install other
  `xamarin.android.support` packages.
- If it didn't work, try to add an **older** version of xamarin forms until it works

  Here is how to search for it: **Xamarin.forms version:***
  [image]